# What's the default line-height in Bootstrap 3? It looks like not 1.428

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use Bootstrap 3 and I put my blog article on my screen. However, the blog looks a bit ugly when I tried to display it, since the line-height seems a bit narrow for some reasons.

Anyway, Bootstrap 3 documentation says it sets the default line-height property to 1.428.

However, when I tried to set my line-height to 135%, with `line-height: 135%;`, the line-height on my blog looks like expanded... weird.

With a little bit of wrangling, I found that the default line-height on my blog is more like 1.15... I'm not sure where this value comes from - I don't set any line-height in all of my CSS settings.

So I wonder, what makes the default value of Bootstrap 3's line-height changed? I have the `<div><div class="blog">`, and within the inner div, I put a lot of `<p>` in order to properly arrange my blog post. Outside of that I don't think I have something related.

So my question is,

1. What decides the value of line-height?
2. Why does the Boostrap 3's default line-height, 1.428, is changed?
3. What is the supposed reason that the about 1.15 value is overwritten (especially it's value - it's not set to 1, but about 1.15...).

I use HTML5 and CSS3 and Bootstrap 3.

[Update]

I found that Bootstrap's line-height is overwritten by my custom CSS setting, specifically this:

```
body
    font: 16px "Lucida Grande", Helvetica
    text-align: center
    background-color: aliceblue
```

However, why is the `line-height` overrode by the above settings? I don't touch on anything related to the line-height property.

For your information my line-height property is set to `normal` right now. Not sure why it's reverted.

Comment: Without knowing your css and html code it is not possible to answer. But you can always check the developer tools to see which rules and in which order are applied for an element, and therefore which rule overwrites the bootstrap default. (you maybe also need step through the parents)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally got what the cause was here. The line of `font: 16px "Lucida Grande", Helvetica` makes the `line-height` property reverted to `normal`, since it sets all the fonts-related settings in one, and since I didn't assign `line-height` to the property, it assumed the default `normal` and overwrote the value inherited from Bootstrap. So replace the line with the following snippet resolves the issue:

```
body
    font-size: 16px
    font-family: "Lucida Grande", Helvetica
```

Answer (score 1):

> What decides the value of line-height?

If your modifing the line-height with less, it is computed. The default is
  `body {line-height: 1.428571429};`
(see CSS file)

The last applied CSS will overwrite the former value. 
So your the CSS File order should be 
bootsrap.css
bootstrap-theme.css (if you have one)
myownstylesheet.css